# importing library Jupyter Notebook vs Canopy

Tags: python, jupyter, canopy

I just installed Canopy because I had some issues running code in Jupyter Notebook.
I have an Anaconda distribution installed.
I installed OpenCV through anaconda and can easily import cv2 in Jupyter Notebook.
However, when I import cv2 in Canopy IDE it says "No module named cv2".

How can I safely fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Python environment is independent. Installing a package into an anaconda Python environment does not install it into a Canopy Python environment (nor into a different anaconda Python environment). This is a feature, not a bug; it allows different Python environments to be configured differently, even incompatibly.

To use OpenCV in Canopy User Python environment, first install it using the Canopy Package Manager.

Comment: Thank you, That's what I did. I forgot to close my own question.
I have had issues with using Canopy together with Anaconda environment so I was hesitant in installing another version of OpenCV that maybe it would cause some issues

Comment: The only way that you should normally get any interactions between different environments (e.g. Canopy and Anaconda) is if you have environment variables set (e.g. PATH) that refer to one of them while you are trying to use another.